# Convergence of power series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a^{\log_en}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, divergent-series

Let $a>0$, the series

$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a^{\log_en}
$$

is convergent for what values of $a$ ?

My attempt:

The usual way I think is to check $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} < 1$ where, $u_n = a^{\log_en}$ and get condition on $a$ This leads to evaluating $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } a^{\log_e \frac{n+1}{n}}$ which is $1$. Right?

But, As we can see for $a=\frac{1}{e} , u_n = (\frac{1}{e})^{\log_en} = -n$ hence, the series diverges.

So, convergence for series happens for $0<a<\frac{1}{e}$, can anyone help me how to arrive at this conclusion using some theorem/result. Any hint will be appreciated ...

Comment: That's not a power series.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

Note that we have

$$a^{\log(n)}=n^{\log(a)}$$

Now, use the $p$ test.

Comment: Excellent and short.

Comment: @DonAntonio Indeed.  I hope that others find it useful.

Comment: @Dr.MV How is $a^{\log_e (n) }  = n^{\log_e (a)}$ could you please explain, After that I got the answer as using $p$-test for $p>1$ series converges here, the equivalent condition is $\log_e \frac{1}{a} > 1$ hence, $a < \frac{1}{e} $

Comment: $$a^{\log(n)}=e^{\log(n)\,\log(a)}=e^{\log(a)\,\log(n)}=n^{\log(a)}$$

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: And feel free to up vote and best vote as you see fit of course.